# Find members in all teams in Tempo/Jira

Tags: python, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to work with the Jira/Tempo API (with Python 2.7), but the documentation is woefully lacking (unless I'm missing something).

#### Goal

The goal is to get a list of all the

1. teams
2. members
3. leaders

#### So far

I've gotten the list of *teams*, but the *members* are all **empty lists** (not so on our site.)

My query URL is:

```
http://myserver.mydomain/rest/tempo-teams/latest/team/?id=expand=true
```

I don't know why the members lists are coming back empty, and I don't really know how to debug or explore this further (this is my first time working with REST/API).

Comment: Even a hint as to where to go or tools to try--I'm out of options of things to experiment with, and the docs are empty (unless I'm looking in the wrong place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http:// yourserver.yourdomain/rest/tempo-teams/latest/team/?expand=members

Answer (score 0):

### Get team *members*

From the Tempo REST API docs for [Teams, Get all members of a team](https://www.tempo.io/server-api-documentation/teams?hsLang=en#operation/getTeamMembers):

> **Get all members of a team**
>
> Team members can be both JIRA users and JIRA groups. In this endpoint the default value for the member type is `user`.
>
> `http://{JIRA_BASE_URL}/rest/tempo-teams/2/team/{id}/member`

The path-variable `{id}` can be replaced with your team-id (integer).
Additional query parameters are:

- *type* (string) where default is `"USER"`
- *onlyActive* (boolean) where default is `false`